# Retrieve Timestamp Data to C++ from MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, date, timestamp

I have 2 strings : startDate and endDate.
In MySQL database, have a TIMESTAMP column. I want to retrieve and insert data using c++

```
string startDate
string endDate

stringstream s;
s << "SELECT * FROM Amts WHERE time >= "<< startDate <<" AND time < "<< endDate <<";";
```

I have recorded some strings like "2014-12-01 14:02:55"
I can't get any record with this query.
I have tried TIME('startDate') but when i try to print the resultset i see 'std::out_of_range'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know `C++` at all so i hope your variables are correct.

Maybe BETWEEN can help you out? Also, wrap with single qoutes.

```
SELECT * FROM Amts WHERE `time` BETWEEN '"<< startDate <<"' AND '"<< endDate <<"';"
```

Comment: Could you also get what the string looks like when its being sent to MySQL server?

Comment: Error Code:# ERR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BETWEEN time >= '2014-01-01 12:55:02' AND time < '2014-11-01 12:55:02'' at line 1 (MySQL error code: 1064, SQLState: 42000 )
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check

Comment: Inserted strings to database like "2014-12-01 00:00:00"

Comment: `'BETWEEN time >= '2014-01-01 12:55:02' AND time < '2014-11-01 12:55:021` is not what i WROTE. use `time BETWEEN date AND date`; Since Time is also a resevred word wrap those also

Comment: Do you have a " wrapped around the data in the database?

Comment: Is the column of type TIMESTAMP?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i forgot to move time to left of between. Now it works..